# How to combine two arrays into one by using array reference using php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two array, one array has color and another array has fruits, here I want to combine using matching color reference.
How to combine by using array reference?

```
$fruits = ['yellow', 'green', 'orange'];


$relatedFurites = [
['yellow'=>'banana', 'green'=>'avacado'],
['yellow'=>'mango', 'green'=> 'chilli']
```

];

expected output by using array refernce

```
$output = [
    'yellow'=>['banana', 'mango'],
    'green'=>['avacado', 'chilli']];
```

Thanks for all suggestions.

Comment: Have you var_dumped the second array? I am sure the result is not what you believe it would be.

Comment: your second array seems wrong  .. is not possible store two different values for the same key

Comment: Hi @scaisEdge,@frz3993, i updated the question

Comment: Is the fruits array a collection of all the colors that is in the array or is it irrelevant to the relatedfruits array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the $fruits array is related as I asked in comments then you can use array_column and you won't have to iterate every item in the array.

```
foreach($fruits as $color){
    $output[$color] = array_column($relatedFurites, $color);
}
var_dump($output);
```

https://3v4l.org/b8tas

Answer (score 0):

You could build the $output array using a nested  foreach

```
foreach ( $relatedFurites as $keyFruites => $valueFruites) {
  foreach( $valueFruites as $key => $value){
    $output[$key][] = $value;
  }

}
```

Comment: why we can't use array reference here?

Comment: Be careful, reference has a different meaning in programming.